# Pluralize "part of speech"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inflector

I want to generate a model called "part of speech". The natural plural to that would be "parts of speech". I can force that with `ActiveSupport::Inflector`, but as far as I can tell, I'd need to do that for "parts_of_speech" and "PartsOfSpeech" to cover all three cases.

This feels a little dirty. Am I approaching this right? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not using `SpeechPart` and `speech_parts` instead? So you have nothing to hack and you can let rails handle naming convention. Specially if you are new to this you should not add the burden of going through this

Comment: It occurs to me there's a regex out there that will match each of those three cases, although coming up with it is something I don't want to do for imaginary points. :)

EDIT: The [list of current inflections in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb) should give you a good head start if you're intent on it, though.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire "Part of speech" is a fixed word with a technical meaning. It is not a phrase that you can rearrange. There is no such word as "speech part" with the same meaning. Nor will a phrase "speech part" help.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for that :) we learn many things on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Just create a file `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and add the following to it:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'part_of_speech', 'parts_of_speech'
end
```

Read more about the `Inflector`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

Comment: Regarding your last line, "part of speech" is a fixed word with a technical meaning. It is not a phrase that you can rearrange. There is no such word as "speech part" with the same meaning. Nor will a phrase "speech part" help.

Comment: @sawa: You are right. I did not know that. Updated my answer.